# Bad request coming while trying to upload file to a sharepoint path

Tags: java, sharepoint, azure-ad-graph-api

we are trying to use graph api registered on Azure AD to set up the file upload automation, but when we are trying the below snippet of code, it gives the 400 bad request error. Any help is appreciated.

```
String siteURL = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename";
 
  String folderUrl = "Shared%20Documents/MS upload test";
  //===============================================//
  //Sharepoint API to create Path
  //===============================================//
  String url1w = siteURL + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('"+folderUrl+"')";
  return "The complete path is : " + url1w;
  URL urlcw = new URL(url1w);
  URLConnection con1 = urlcw.openConnection();
  HttpURLConnection httpCon1 = (HttpURLConnection) con1;
  httpCon1.setDoOutput(true);
  httpCon1.setDoInput(true);
  httpCon1.setRequestMethod("POST");
  httpCon1.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
  DataOutputStream wr1 = new DataOutputStream(httpCon1.getOutputStream());
  wr1.flush();
  wr1.close();
  // Read the response.
  String respStr1 = "";
  if (httpCon1.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    respStr1 = "Path has been found/created successfully. ResponseCode : " + httpCon1.getResponseCode();
  } else {
    respStr1 += "Error while writing file, ResponseCode : " + httpCon1.getResponseCode() + " "+ httpCon1.getResponseMessage();
  }return respStr1;
```

respStr1 returns the error message as "Error while writing file, ResponseCode : 400 Bad Request"

Link used for reference is [here](http://gotobo.in/sharepoint-upload-and-download-codes-java/#content)

Answer (score 0):

`400 Bad Request` usually indicates `invalid or malformed` request or when content-type is  wrong .

- please make sure two main headers Authorization and `Content-Type`
  are defined which are necessary along with other headers.
- Make sure content type is set that has the form your data has i.e.;
  It should reflect the content type of your data.
- For example, if your content body is XML , Content-Type should be set
  with 'application/xml', for JSON, “application/json '', etc.. If
  content is plain text, simply set 'text/plain' or multipart/form-data
  with boundary

*Examples:*

> ```
> 1. conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json")
> 2. conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
> 3. conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
> 4. conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
> 5. conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html, text/plain,application/json,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
> ```

Also check if content size declaration can be given according to file size.

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "" + fileSize);
```

check out available content types [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type).

Comment: Hi , I tried adding the content type to the request property, its still the same :/